# Weka StringToWordVector Filter - Implementation in Java

Tags: java, text, filter, weka, stop-words

I started trying out the Weka GUI application to learn how I want to build my text classifier and I successfully built and saved a model using the GUI.

Now, I want to implement the classifier in Java code. **But I can't seem to set the stopwords and tokenizer settings of the StringToWordVector filter in code like I did in the GUI**. (See the screenshot.)

[image]

*(Of course, without the stopwords handler set to NULL.)*

I am aware that I can load the model I created and saved from the GUI, into the code. But I need to implement the filter in Java.

I tried to use the code here: [Different results in Weka GUI and Weka via Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456126/different-results-in-weka-gui-and-weka-via-java-code)
Mainly, this part (of course, after changing the path):

```
 String opt = "-W -P 0 -M 5.0 -norm 1.0 -lnorm 2.0 -lowercase -stoplist -        stopwords C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\GPCommentsAnalyzer\\pt-br_stopwords.dat -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.NGramTokenizer -delimiters ' \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\' -max 2 -min 1\" -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer";
```

But, it still doesn't work.

I can't find any documentation about this topic anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

*(I am using Weka version 3.7.12)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your configuration using GUI, then use copy configuration to clipboard option in context menu.

[image: Copy config to clipboard]

Comment: http://imgur.com/VVhCisZ

I tried your suggestion, but the errors in the attached image came up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1910524 I can't see your image.

Comment: @user1910524 I think you should use as  String str=" -R first-last ...", that is your option string should not contain filter name since you already set filter in your code before.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know again. Thank you Atilla.

Comment: Hello again Atilla, I have been working on the classifier, and implemented your notes/advice. The classifier is working, but under certain conditions. I wanted to be able to set the stopwordsHandler to a file in which I will put my own stopwords (as opposed to the Rainbow stopwords). When I try to use stopwords from my own file, it doesn't work. (Please see the image here: http://imgur.com/culPw1Z,PF7EfGn) When I use the Rainbow stopwords, the classifier works, and classifies successfully. (Please see the image here: http://imgur.com/culPw1Z,PF7EfGn#1) Why is this?